# reading in a large amount of lines in C (csv files)

Tags: c, file, csv, input

I have an input .csv file which is formatted like so:

```
10012,85
11981,100
10728,65
```

Where the first number is a student ID, followed by a grade on an exam. I need to be able to read an indefinite number of these lines, but I'm not sure how to in C. I couldn't format fscanf properly (kept giving me runtime errors/crashes). This is my attempt (note the struct is just how I'll be using the gathered data from the files later):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int i = 0;
FILE *inf;
struct List list = SLL_new();

for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    inf = fopen(argv[i], "r");
    int studentID = 0;
    int grade = 0;
    if(inf == NULL){
        printf("bad");
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(inf, "%d,%d", &studentID, &grade);
    printf("%d, %d", studentID, grade);
}
```

}

}

This is my output when run with the input file at the top (pre-edit, when I was using fread):

```
C:\Users\witcher\Documents\NJIT\CS 288>a midterm01.csv
10012,85
11981,100
10728,65δ
```

I don't think this works with more lines, and regardless, the special character at the end is also confusing to me. I need to read these values as ints, but if I use fread then I need to cast them or something along those lines later.

Comment: `char buf[128];` then `fread(buf, 256, 2, inf);` that's unsafe.

Comment: Can change one or the other, but I don't think that's my issue here. I don't understand the 2nd and 3rd parameters to fread very well.

Comment: you shouldn't put `fopen` inside the loop... Open the file only one time to avoid memory leak

Comment: @xing gives me a runtime error: https://gyazo.com/1c3d9e8b46660bf917992f8e5bb5e6cf

Comment: Why is `if(inf == NULL)` in the loop?

Comment: Unless this is an exercise to learn C, there is no reason to do this sort of thing in C.  What are you trying to do?  If the answer is "learn c", then by all means proceed.  If the answer is anything else, stop trying to do this in C.

Comment: `inf = fopen(argv[i], "r");` : `i` is uninitialized.

Comment: Does not your complier warn about `int studentID = 0;
    int grade = 0;   ... printf("%s, %s", studentID, grade);`?  Can you enable more warnings?

Comment: No, I use GCC & command. Not sure how I'd do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reading ints, and trying to print strings;

```
fscanf(inf, "%d,%d", &studentID, &grade);
printf("%s, %s", studentID, grade);
```

Should be

```
fscanf(inf, "%d,%d", &studentID, &grade);
printf("%d, %d", studentID, grade);
```

To read the whole file try

```
while (2 == fscanf(inf, "%d,%d", &studentID, &grade))
{
    printf("%d, %d", studentID, grade);
}
fclose(inf);
```

Comment: Well, that's a little silly of me. The runtime error is gone, but now the check for null file stream exits the function.

Comment: @AnthonyB as @BLUEPIXY says `inf = fopen(argv[i], "r");` : i is uninitialized. try `inf = fopen(argv[1], "r");`

Comment: I need to be able to iterate over an indefinite number of command line arguments (files), so the second wouldn't work. I did initialize i in the beginning of main, so I don't understand why it's an issue.

Comment: @AnthonyB You need two loops.  one for i..argc and one to read to the end of the file.  Don't use argv[i] before setting i

Comment: How would I acquire the number of lines in the file to iterate over in c?

Comment: @AnthonyB You don't acquire the number of lines.  You can get the size in bytes but that's not the same.  Just keep calling fscanf(...) until it doesn't return the two items read and you'll be at the end of the file.

Comment: If I call fscanf 4 times (on a 3 line input file for example), it will always return the last line no matter what. How would I add a check for this without having to watch for duplicates?